# Javascript load/read text file by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a button, instead of this input box to load the text file. When I press the button, I want to load a text file called "me.txt" without showing a browse window. ("me.txt" is in the same path). Is there anyway to do that?

```
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">

<script>
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

  var file = this.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      var wordStr = (lines[line]);
      var index = wordStr.indexOf("=");  // Gets the first index where a space occours
      var word = wordStr.substr(0, index); // Gets the first part
      var meaning = wordStr.substr(index + 1);

      if (word=="a") {
          document.write(meaning);
      }
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "in the same path"? Is your webpage opened via an http server? Or it just opened via file schema?

Comment: That is not possible, to open a file on someone's computer without them choosing one first ... would be a **huge** security issue

Comment: If the file on the server then simple GET request will do. If the file is use local file system, then it's not possible without input[type=file]

Comment: If you explain what you want to do with that file (and its content), and how/why it ended up there in the first place, we might be able to help solving it in an a way that will work

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very active place, even on the weekend, with people who are really eager to help you. When you ask a question, please *stick around* for a few minutes so you can answer questions like tsh's above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read a file from the user's computer without the user actively picking the file; and you cannot know the real path of that file on the user's computer. Browsers quite rightly prevent both of those things.

> When I press the button, I want to load a text file called "me.txt" without showing a browse window. ("me.txt" is in the same path).

If you mean that `me.txt` is a file that's on the same path as the HTML page this code is running in, then:

1. If you're using a web server process and accessing the page via `http://` or `https://`, you can use a simple ajax request to read the file, for instance:

   ```
   $.get("me.txt").then(function(data) {
       // ...use data...
   });
   ```
2. If you're just running from the local file system (a `file:///` URL), it's **much** better to use a local web server process instead. But if you have to use a `file:///` URL, you can't read other local files in Chrome, but you can in Firefox:

   ```
   // NOT allowed from file:/// URLs not work in Chrome; is allowed in Firefox
   $.ajax({
       url: "test.json",
       dataType: "text"
   }).then(function(data) {
       // ...use data here
   });
   ```

   Firefox will report an XML parsing error in the console, but will also give you the data.